# No me cargan los modelos

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

sé que he preguntado mucho por aquí. Pero ahora es un problema que escapa a mi entendimiento, he subido toda mi información a esta página http://juanpablofinal.com

Sucede, que cuando intento acceder, me tira el error

> "An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to locate the model you have specified: loginmodel"

Lo pueden comprobar por ustedes mismo,no sé por qué sucede. De manera local me funciona de maravilla.

Aquí mis códigos.

```
<?php

class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function process()
    {
        $this->load->model("LoginModel");
        $this->load->model('AccountModel');
        //$this->load->library('javascript');
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");

        if ($this->LoginModel->Login($username, $password))
        {
            $data["Cuentas"] = $this->AccountModel->getAllAccountInfo();
            $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php

class AccountModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function getAllAccountInfo()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito FROM accounts');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function saveData()
    {

    }
}

?>

<?php 
class LoginModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function Login($user, $pass)
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $user);
        $this->db->where('password', $pass);
        $query = $this->db->get('usuarios');
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo php de tu modelo?

Comment: Están dos modelos. El LoginModel.php que es que está dando error.  y AccountModel.php que ya es dentro de la aplicación que llama a la base de datos para visualizar los resultados en una tabla. Como he dicho anteriormente, de manera local no me ha presentado ningún tipo de este error, sigo probando y me funciona bien. Pero ya subido en la web me sale eso!.

Comment: Si estan bien los nombres de los archivos. En tu archivo de configuracion de codeigniter, **¿que tienes en `$config['base_url']` y `$config['index_page']`?**, **¿tienes un archivo .htacces para quitar el index.php de tu url?**

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://juanpablofinal.com';
$config['index_page'] = ''; //la tenía llena con index.php pero lo quité. 


Y si tengo .htacces.

Comment: Hermano, ya busqué una solución propia. Era que me lo estaba reconociendo las letras como minúsculas, no entiendo el porqué. Gracias por ofrecerme tu ayuda en todas mis preguntas!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,
Prueba con Account_model tanto en la declaracion de la clase como en el nombre del archivo y con Login_model. Todo esto generalmente puede ser por la versión de codeigniter y la versión de php que tengas instalada.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm el error es claro obvio en mi opinión el  problema es `index` osea no encuentra el modulo de `loginmodel`  el cual esta en `index.PHP` y están intentando entrar a un archivo que en el código no existe yo te recomendaría en `PHP` no quites las extensión con `PHP` sino con `apache`?porque el usuario cuando esta entrando a tu web recibirá el resultado preconfigurado en apache para todos los archivos  pero en realidad jamás se los cambiarías en el mero código esa es mi opinión sobre 'PHP` y tu problemas y hay mucha información de esto en Internet (en ingles)